# Получение пакетов в пространство пользователя Linux

Tags: linux, golang, сеть

Написал утилиту на Golang для обработки заголовков TCP/IP, для захвата пакетов в userspace использую libnetfilter_nfqueue, скорость конечно падает, из-за копирования пакетов через ядро, интересует есть ли какие-либо альтернативвы очередям netllibnetfilter_nfqueue, для доставки изменения и вставки пакетов в сетевой интрфейс.Увидел такую фичу как DMA, есть ли возможность её использовать,если да то хотелось бы примеров,чтобы посмотреть как это работает.

Answer (score 3):

> Увидел такую фичу как DMA, есть ли возможность её использовать

Нет, DMA используется драйверами ядра для общения с устройствами. Вообще говоря, из пользовательского пространства возможно взаимодействовать с устройством напрямую через DMA, но для этого, во-первых, должен быть специальный драйвер в ядре, который предоставит этот доступ, так, например, работает графическая подсистема в linux. И, во-вторых, в данном случае пришлось бы написать полноценный драйвер сетевой карты и реализацию стека IP в пользовательском пространстве, что, само собой, за пределами разумного для задачи фильтрации пакетов, хотя, например, проект [dpdk](https://www.dpdk.org/) по факту это и делает.

> есть ли какие-либо альтернативвы очередям netllibnetfilter_nfqueue, для доставки изменения и вставки пакетов в сетевой интрфейс

`nfqueue` нужен для произвольной фильтрации/изменения пакетов, предназначенных другим приложениям. Для простого чтения/отправки пакетов L2 OSI есть пакетные сырые сокеты(`AF_PACKET`/`SOCK_RAW`), см. подробности в [`man 7 packet`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=packet&category=7&russian=0). Они не позволят фильтровать/изменять пакеты, но и не будут значительно тормозить обмен по сети другими приложениями.

Собственно альтернативой является написание модуля ядра для netfilter.

Также для увеличения скорости можно в nfqueue отправлять не все пакеты, а предварительно отфильтровать нужные средствами ядра, т.е., например, создать правило `iptables` вида:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 8080 -j NFQUEUE
```

Comment: Забыли упомянуть про Intel DPDK: https://www.dpdk.org/

Comment: @0andriy, упомянул, но на мой вкус сомнительная штука... 1—2 лишнее переключение контекста может плохо сказаться на производительности, а отчёты о сравнения скорости мне лень искать... хотя я тот ещё технический ретроград...